# What rules allow you to crush a sufficiently small target?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, combat, combat-maneuver, unarmed-combat

We all know that a human can crush an insect in less than six seconds.
How does one crush in pathfinder, given the size difference is substantial enough?

Would it be considered a [bull rush](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/combat#TOC-Bull-Rush) for a colossal centaur to step on a human?
Would a human need to [maintain a grapple for 3 turns](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/combat#TOC-Grapple) to crush an insect?
Would you use the rules for a [falling object's damage](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/environment/environmental-rules/#Falling_Objects) listed under acrobatics?

As far as I can tell, there's no combat maneuver to do this, but it's clearly something that should be able to happen.

Comment: Answers must use rules citations or playtested homebrew - answers just speculating “what they might do” will be deleted without notice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no general rule about this, but a very close ability is the [Crush](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/dragons/dragon#TOC-Combat) special attack of dragon creatures.

> Crush (Ex): A flying or jumping Huge or larger dragon can land on foes as a standard action, using its whole body to crush them. Crush attacks are effective only against opponents three or more size categories smaller than the dragon. A crush attack affects as many creatures as fit in the dragon’s space. Creatures in the affected area must succeed on a Reflex save (DC equal to that of the dragon’s breath weapon) or be pinned, automatically taking bludgeoning damage during the next round unless the dragon moves off them. If the dragon chooses to maintain the pin, it must succeed at a combat maneuver check as normal. Pinned foes take damage from the crush each round if they don’t escape. A crush attack deals the indicated damage plus 1-1/2 times the dragon’s Strength bonus.

Unlike Trample, this ability is restricted to creatures three sizes smaller, takes only a standard action, does not require an Overrun maneuver, and deals continuous damage. Damage are 2d8 (Huge), 4d6 (Gargantuan) or 4d8 (Colossal).

This doesn't cause an instant death (insta-kill from damage in Pathfinder is only covered with the optional [Massive Damage](https://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/coreRulebook/combat.html#massive-damage) rules, which can but don't necessarily apply here), but it is perfectly possible that a weak creature would instantly die from being crushed.

Answer (score 8):

> Would it be considered a bull rush for a colossal centaur to step on a human?

No, it would be considered a hoof attack - if the damage was sufficient to kill the human then it could be described as the human being crushed.

This is how human's crush insects - they make an unarmed attack, do the 1 point of damage needed to kill them and the insect is then crushed.

Comment: I like this answer, but that means that things with enough hit points can survive being squished.

Comment: yes, that's what hit points are *for*

Comment: @ErinBailey ["Hit points mean two things in the game world: the ability to take physical punishment and keep going, and the ability to turn a serious blow into a less serious one."](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/coreRulebook/combat.html#loss-of-hit-points) Presumably, more experienced folk do the latter rather than getting instagibbed by centaurs.

Answer (score 3):

You're looking for the [trample](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/rules-for-monsters/universal-monster-rules/#Trample_Ex) monster ability:

> As a full-round action, a creature with the trample ability can attempt to overrun any creature that is at least one size category smaller than itself. This works just like the overrun combat maneuver, but the trampling creature does not need to make a check, it merely has to move over opponents in its path. Targets of a trample take an amount of damage equal to the trampling creature’s slam damage + 1-1/2 times its Str modifier. Targets of a trample can make an attack of opportunity, but at a –4 penalty. If targets forgo an attack of opportunity, they can attempt to avoid the trampling creature and receive a Reflex save to take half damage.

One example of a creature with this ability is the [elephant](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/animals/elephant/elephant/).

Pathfinder does not, in general, have rules for insta-killing things -- that does not lead to fun combats.  But this is a way to deal a significant amount of damage to a thing just by stomping on it.